# Getting error alert "invalid string"while excuting CQL query statement

Tags: mysql, sql, cql

I am new to CQL. In my CQL database have many columns. There is a requirement, I need populate data based on checking string value of particular column.

When I execute this query `select * from posts`, I'm able to see all columns value. But when I execute the below query.

```
select guid from posts where post_id='da9ef16f-18ee-36df-840a-3ef559ee278c';
```

[image]

Getting error and Attached screen shot within for same. Please let me know.
Greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UUID's will be treated as a string if you use single quotes in CQL. Try the following:

```
select guid from posts where post_id=da9ef16f-18ee-36df-840a-3ef559ee278c;
```

This will parse as a UUID instead of string literal